# Find $PR$ in the line segment below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

On a straight line, the consecutive points $P, Q, R$ and $S$ are considered which form a harmonic quatern.
If $QR=\frac{47}{QS}$ and $PS =\frac{96}{PQ}$, calculate $PR$
(Answer:$7$)

My progress:

I used the property of the quatern in line segments and the theorem of Descartes

$\frac{PQ}{QR}=\frac{PS}{RS}(I)$ (property)$

R. Descartes:$ \frac{2}{PR} = \frac{1}{PQ} + \frac{1}{PS}\implies \frac{2}{PR} = \frac{PS}{96}+\frac{PQ}{96}$

$PR=\frac{192}{(PS+PQ)}$

From(I): $ \frac{PQ}{PR-PQ} =\frac{PS+RS}{RS}\implies PQRS = PRPS+PRRS-PQPS-PQRS$

$2PQRS+PQPS=PR(PS+RS)\implies PQ(2RS+PS) = PR(PS+RS) $

I can't find the algebra to finish;;;?

Comment: What is 'harmonic quatern'?

Comment: @ACB  the collinear and consecutive points A, B, C and D form an harmonic quatern if and only if: $\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{AD}{CD}$  Properties of the harmonic quatern: $AB > BC$; $\frac{2}{AC} = \frac{1}{AB}+\frac{1}{AD}$

Comment: @ACB   These questions are more for developing an algebraic form until finding the solution using only the properties and mathematical algebraism